How to configure Ollama on Ubuntu to access from Windows 11 on local LAN
Ollama is running fine on my Ubuntu machine, and works locally there. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. From Windows 11 in Python, I try:
client = Client(host='http://127.0.1.1:11434')
response = client.chat(model='phi3:3.8b-mini-128k-instruct-q4_0', messages=[
  {
    'role': 'user',
    'content': 'Why is the sky blue?',
  },
])

I get this error on the Windows/Python side:
ConnectError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

And on the Ubuntu side I see this appear:--
Connection Failed: Activation of Network Connection Failed

I want to connect the two machines locally via LAN, off the Internet, so I have an ethernet cable run from the Linux machine to a USB/Ethernet adapter on the Windows machine (the Linux machine is not on the Internet and I don't want it to be--Windows machine is on the Internet via a different ethernet port.)
I get the impression I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here. Is there something else I need to configure on Ubuntu or Windows to get this connection working?
